# Prove that for any real number $x > 0$ and for any $M > 0$ there is $N ∈ \mathbb N$ so that if $n > N$ then $(1 + x)^n > M.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Prove that for any real number $x > 0$ and for any $M > 0$ there is $N ∈ \mathbb N$ so that if $n > N$ then $(1 + x)^n > M.$

A sequence ${a_n}$ diverges to $+\infty$ if for any $M > 0$ there is $N ∈\mathbb N$ so that if $n > N$ then $a_n > M$. Suppose ${a_n}$ diverges to $+\infty$ and $a_n \ne 0$ for all $n$. Prove that in this case $\frac{1}{a_n}$ converges to $0$.

How do I approach these proofs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,M>0$, then $(1+x)^{n} \geq nx +1$ $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ (Bernoulli)

So, if I take $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > \frac{M - 1}{x}$

then if $n > N$, $(1+x)^{n} \geq nx +1 > Nx + 1 >\frac{M - 1}{x}x + 1 = M$

Second part:

Suppose $a_{n} \to \infty$, $a_{n} \not= 0$ $\forall n$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, then $\frac{1}{\varepsilon} > 0$

So, there's exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > N$ then $a_{n} > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$

Thus if $n > N$, then $\frac{1}{a_{n}} < \varepsilon$

So, $\frac{1}{a_{n}} \to o$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use *Bernoulli's inequality* if $x>-1$, then
$$ (1+x)^n\ge1+nx. $$